# Proving that the set of vectors is not basis for R^3

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> let $B = 
> \begin{Bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1
> \\ 0
> \\ 1
> \end{bmatrix},
> \begin{bmatrix}
> -2
> \\ 1
> \\ 1
> \end{bmatrix}
> \end{Bmatrix}
> $, show that $B$ is not a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

From the definition of a basis, we must have $\text{span} \space \{ B\} = S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and that $B$ is linearly independent.

**Fact:** It is true that $B$ is a linearly independent vector set, so we must disprove the first part of the definition.

So our goal is to disprove that $\text{span} \space \{B\} \ne S = \mathbb{R}^3$?

**So in our case** it is true that $S = \mathbb{R}^3$ right?

Comment: how many do you need for basis? For, $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ you need a minimum of some numbers...

Comment: @HumbleStudent, I know we need $3$, but that is not a dis-proof. That is the intuitive step,  I want to completely disprove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to find a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that cannot be represented as a linear combination of the given basis.

To this end, let us take $a=(-1,3,1)^\top$ and this vector will do the job.

Comment: Which theorem is this? Why must one vector be written as a combination of others in the basis?

Comment: @Gaandmit, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis for detail of the definition of basis.

Comment: We could also use $(1, 0, -1)$ right?

Comment: @Gaandmit Yes, it is correct. Actually, I just take the vector that perpendicular to the plane spanned by the given two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive about your notation/definition, but for $B$ to be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, must have Span(B) = $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $B$ linearly independent. Since the vectors are LI, yes, your goal is to show Span(B)$ \ne \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: So to show that last statement, if we can find one example in $$\mathbb{R}^3$$ that shows that $span(B)$ does not work then we have the proof?

Comment: @Gaandmit right, just need to find a vector in R_3 that can't be written as a linear combo of the two vectors in B.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

*Proof by contradiction:*

For e.g. show that $\begin{bmatrix}
1
\\ 1
\\ 1
\end{bmatrix}$ cannot be written using $B$.

Comment: But $(0, 0, 0)$ can be written with all coefficients $=0$

Comment: Oh, I meant $[1,1,1]$. Rectified.